# Can't transfer data from cross-pc using TCP

Tags: c++, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

So I ran my TCP client and server on my own pc, and it worked fine. But when I got my friend to run the client and I ran the server, it came up with Error 10057.

TCP Server:

```
#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
# pragma warning(disable:4996)
using namespace std;
int main()
{


    cout << "\t\t------TCP Server-------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    WSADATA Winsockdata;
    int iWsaStartup;
    int iWsaCleanup;

    SOCKET TCPServerSocket;
    int iCloseSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in TCPServerAdd;
    struct sockaddr_in TCPClientAdd;
    int iTCPClientAdd = sizeof(TCPClientAdd);
    int iBind;
    int iListen;
    SOCKET sAcceptSocket;
    int iSend;
    char SenderBuffer[512] = "Hello from server";
    int iSenderBuffer = strlen(SenderBuffer) + 1;
    int iRecv;
    char RecvBuffer[512];
    int iRecvBuffer = strlen(RecvBuffer) + 1;

    //Step-1 WSAStartup Fun------------------------------------

    iWsaStartup = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Winsockdata);
    if (iWsaStartup != 0)
    {
        cout << "WSAStartup Failed" << endl;
    }
    cout << "WSAStartup Success" << endl;

    // STEP -2 Fill the structure-------------------------------

    TCPServerAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
    TCPServerAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    TCPServerAdd.sin_port = htons(8000);

    //Step -3 Socket Creation------------------------------------

    TCPServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (TCPServerSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "TCP Server Socket Creation failed" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }

    //Step -4 bind fun------------------------------------------

    iBind = bind(TCPServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&TCPServerAdd, sizeof(TCPServerAdd));
    if (iBind == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Binding Failed &Error No->" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;

    }
    cout << "Binding success" << endl;

    //STEP-5 Listen fun------------------------------------------

    iListen = listen(TCPServerSocket, 2);
    if (iListen == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Listen fun failed &error No->" << WSAGetLastError();
    }
    cout << "Listen fun success" << endl;

    // STEP-6 Accept---------------------------------------------

    sAcceptSocket = accept(TCPServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&TCPClientAdd, &iTCPClientAdd);
    if (sAcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Accept failed & Error No ->" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Accept fun success" << endl;

    // STEP-7 Send Data to the client

    iSend = send(sAcceptSocket, SenderBuffer, iSenderBuffer, 0);
    if (iSend == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Sending Failed & Error No->" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Send fun success" << endl;

    // STEP -8 Recv Data from Client

    iRecv = recv(sAcceptSocket, RecvBuffer, iRecvBuffer, 0);
    if (iRecv == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Receiving Failed & Error No->" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Receive fun success" << endl;
    cout << "Data Received -> " << RecvBuffer << endl;

    //STEP - 9 Close Socket


    iCloseSocket = closesocket(TCPServerSocket);

    if (iCloseSocket == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Closing Failed & Error No->" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Cleanup fun success" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

TCP Client

```
#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
# pragma warning(disable:4996)
using namespace std;
int main()
{


    cout << "\t\t------TCP Client-------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    WSADATA Winsockdata;
    int iWsaStartup;
    int iWsaCleanup;

    SOCKET TCPClientSocket;
    int iCloseSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in TCPServerAdd;
    int iConnect;

    int iSend;
    char SenderBuffer[512] = "Hello from client";
    int iSenderBuffer = strlen(SenderBuffer) + 1;
    int iRecv;
    char RecvBuffer[512];
    int iRecvBuffer = strlen(RecvBuffer) + 1;

    //Step-1 WSAStartup Fun------------------------------------

    iWsaStartup = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Winsockdata);
    if (iWsaStartup != 0)
    {
        cout << "WSAStartup Failed" << endl;
    }
    cout << "WSAStartup Success" << endl;

    //Step -2 Socket Creation------------------------------------

    TCPClientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (TCPClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "TCP Client Socket Creation failed" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "TCP client socket creation success";
    // STEP -3 Fill the structure-------------------------------

    TCPServerAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
    TCPServerAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    TCPServerAdd.sin_port = htons(8000);

    // STEP-4 Connect fun---------------------------------------------

    iConnect = connect(TCPClientSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&TCPServerAdd, sizeof(TCPServerAdd));
    if (iConnect == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Connection failed & Error No ->" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Connection success" << endl;

    // STEP -5 Recv Data from Server

    iRecv = recv(TCPClientSocket, RecvBuffer, iRecvBuffer, 0);
    if (iRecv == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Receiving Failed & Error No->" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Receive fun success" << endl;
    cout << "Data Received -> " << RecvBuffer << endl;

    // STEP-6 Send Data to the server

    iSend = send(TCPClientSocket, SenderBuffer, iSenderBuffer, 0);
    if (iSend == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Sending Failed & Error No->" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Data sending success" << endl;

    //STEP - 7 Close Socket

    iCloseSocket = closesocket(TCPClientSocket);
    if (iCloseSocket == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Closing Failed & Error No->" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "Closing Socket success" << endl;


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried editing the ip's on the server to my own port forwarded IP and that didn't work.
I expected me to be able to transfer from the server to the client and the client to the server.
What happened was the Error 10057 occurred.

Comment: You need to change both the server and client IPs for it to work. `127.0.0.1` will neither make your port listen for connections from different machines, nor connect to a different machine. Also you must keep in mind, that your firewall may block incoming connections on the server side. Could you include a more detailed description of the Error? Did it occur on the client or on the server. How far did the program proceed until the error occured?

Comment: Error 10057 is "The socket is not connected"